# Is it possible to run and train a neural network on an 8-bit microcontroller?

Tags: smart-home, microcontrollers, machine-learning

I've recently read about neural networks in constrained environments (in particular, [A Neural Network Implementation on an Inexpensive Eight Bit Microcontroller](http://www.eng.auburn.edu/~wilambm/pap/2008/A%20Neural%20Network%20Implementation%20on%20an%20Inexpensive%20Eight%20Bit%20Microcontroller.pdf)) and their applications to IoT devices (e.g. regression for predicting things based on sensor inputs, etc).

This seems ideal for simple applications where processing is not time-critical, and the data to process will be relatively infrequent. However, further research suggests that training a neural network in a resource-constrained environment is a poor idea (see the answer to [Is it possible to run a neural network on a microcontroller](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/569)).

Does this still apply for Cotton, Wilamowski and Dündar's approach that I linked? Would it be necessary to train a network designed for low resource usage on a more powerful device in my IoT network?

For context, if I had a sensor transmitting the heat setting, I am considering a neural network as described in the paper to predict the desired boiler setting based on that and the time of day, etc. Training would be useful to change the neural network's outputs based on more data provided by the user. [This Quora question](https://www.quora.com/What-machine-learning-algorithms-are-used-in-Nest-thermostat) describes a similar scenario well, and discusses the implementation details for a neural network, but my question is more focused on whether running the network on the actuator itself would work.

Comment: Curios, do you intend to run a neural network on each sensor/actuator node or at some (semi-)centralized "brain" (then of course the 8-bit restriction wouldn't necessarily apply)?

Comment: @Ghanima if possible, I'd like to do it at the actuator node to save the extra layer of complexity, although I'm not sure whether that would work with the limited constraints.

Comment: @Aurora0001  The particular controller you site here may not be suited to train your NN but, there are concerted efforts in the embedded computer-vision world to do exactly that. If you are trying to find a micro-controller with an architecture suited for such tasks, I suggest that you look to the companies developing these kinds of hardware for the computer-vision industry.  I am sure some of it can be repurposed and adapted to your requirements.  [A good place to start](http://www.embedded-vision.com/platinum-members-embedded-vision-alliance)

Comment: @grldsndrs fantastic, thanks for the reference. Feel free to post it as an additional answer if you feel that it's enough (I'd certainly be happy with it)

Comment: An 8 bit processor can do anything a wider-word processor can, only perhaps (depends on the task) more slowly.  However, 8 bit processors tend to have limited native address space, which means they must use indirect means to manage very large memories, and in the case of microcontrollers tend to ship with comparably small amounts of on-chip memory.   There's increasingly little cost difference beyond the lowest-end - the primary driver of MCU cost is arguably memories, not ALU width.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According the [first paper](http://www.eng.auburn.edu/~wilambm/pap/2008/A%20Neural%20Network%20Implementation%20on%20an%20Inexpensive%20Eight%20Bit%20Microcontroller.pdf), running is not a problem. That was the purpose. Only there is a limitation on the maximum weights:

> Currently  the  limitation on  the  architecture  embedded  in  this  microcontroller  is  limited  only  by  the  number  of  weights  needed.    The  neural  network  is  currently  limited  to  256  weights.    However  for  most  embedded  applications  this  256  weight  should  not  limit the system.

---

As for training, as far as I understand the implementation described, the PIC controller receives parameters from an external source.

> The  neural  network  forward  calculations  are  written  so  that  each  neuron  is  calculated  individually  in  a  series  of  nested  loops.  The number of calculations for each loop and values for  each  node  are  all  stored  in  a  simple  array  in  memory.
>
> [...]
>
> These  arrays  contain  the  architecture  and    the    weights    of    the    network.        Currently,    for    demonstration  purposes,  these  arrays  are  preloaded  at  the  time  the  chip  is  programmed,  but  in  the  final  version  this  would  not  be  necessary.    The  microcontroller  could  easily  be  modified  to  contain  a  simple  boot  loader  that  makes  use  of  the  onboard  RS232  serial  port  which  would  receive  the  data for the weights and topography from a remote location.  This would allow for the weights or even the entire network 
>   to be modified while the chip is in the field.

I suspect that the training is performed externally as well.

The paper also gives references for Neural Network Trainers which were probably used to determine the values preprogrammed into the PIC's memory.

- [Wilamowski,  B.  M.;  Cotton,  N.;  Hewlett,  J.;  Kaynak,  O., 
  "Neural   Network   Trainer   with   Second   Order   Learning Algorithms,"](http://www.eng.auburn.edu/~wilambm/pap/2007/Neural%20Network%20Trainer%20with%20Second%20Order%20Learning%20Algorithms.PDF)
- Wilamowski,  B.  M.;  Cotton,  N.  J.;  Kaynak,  O.;  Dundar,  G.,
  "Method of computing gradient vector and Jacobean matrix in 
  arbitrarily connected neural networks,"

Now, I have looked into the first one which describes network architectures
and algorithms to use with them. But the Neural Network Trainer software used here is implemented in MATLAB.

> Currently, there is very little neural network training software available
>   that will train fully connected networks. Thus a package with a graphical user interface has been developed in MATLAB for that purpose. This software
>   allows the user to easily enter very complex architectures as well as initial
>   weights, training parameters, data sets, and the choice of several powerful
>   algorithms.

I have to mention that the fully connected networks has lower weights number for a same task than a layer by layer architecture. That makes it more suitable for microcontrollers.

I am not a neural network expert and it is quite complex so I can be wrong, but based on these papers I would say that Cotton, Wilamowski and Dündar's approach requires an external, more powerful platform to perform the training.

---

About running a neural network on a microcontroller, ST Microelectronics just announced a toolkit [STM32Cube.AI: Convert Neural Networks into Optimized Code for STM32](https://blog.st.com/stm32cubeai-neural-networks/?fbclid=IwAR3iWyFIDLSk6FufU9spDyTQPF1G8Ngkoozsv1f0eDT8hLCEWnQst900GDU) to convert **pre-trained** neural networks from popular libraries to most of their STM32 MCUs.